# Problem with sansmathaccent under pdftex

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I get the following error when I try to typeset a beamer document.

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+525/600 --dpi
525 mathkerncmssi8 gsftopk: fatal: map file `cid-base.map' not found.
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mathkerncmssi8.
mktexpk: perhaps mathkerncmssi8 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.  ) !pdfTeX
error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 525 not
found  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

But if I remove `sansmathaccent.sty` from the TeX Live tree, the document typesets fine.
Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{A very short beamer document} 
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$ 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On my system it compiles fine. What system and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: this works fine for me `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{A very short beamer document} 
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$ 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}`, perhaps [an update is in order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/6621)

Comment: Looks as if the `map`-file has not been activated (probably due to the known `updmap`/`udpmap-sys` confusion). Try if it works if you add `\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}` to your document. If yes you will have to find out how to get the map-entries permanantly in your `pdftex.map`.

Comment: Problem fixed.  Thanks Ulrike for the big hint.  The file typeset fine with `\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}` added.  I then ran `updmap-sys --enable Map=sansmathaccent.map` and still had the problem, but then I discovered a local `pdftex.map` file, and the problem went away once I removed the local file.  Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you make an answer from your comment?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Adding \pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map} worked. Could you please explain how to "call updmap to update the existing local pdftex.map" using Miktex in Windows 10? Sorry for not adding as a comment to the answer, but my reputation is not high enough for posting comments.

Answer (score 9):

Looks as if the `map`-file has not been activated (probably due to the known `updmap`/`udpmap-sys` confusion in a multiuser setup). Try if it works if you add `\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}` to your document. If yes you will have to find out how to get the map-entries permanantly in your `pdftex.map`.

In miktex the easiest way is to call `updmap` to update the existing local `pdftex.map`.