# beamer doesn't compile

Tags: beamer, lyx, font-encodings

This is a LyX question... I updated my LyX to the latest 2.1.0 and since then it does not compile the PDF file when I use `beamer` (other files it compiles fine). I get the following error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 600 not found
```

I tried to re-install LyX with the complete MiKTeX environment (bundle) and it still doesn't work. i updated MiKTeX too and still doesn't work.

I would be very grateful for any help. Please note that I am a complete anti-tech, I know nothing about LaTeX (hence LyX!), so please write your answer accordingly.

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/problem-with-sansmathaccent-under-pdftex ?

Comment: did you try this ? [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133781/font-display-error-in-windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133781/font-display-error-in-windows)