# miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The t1xbtt source file could not be found

Tags: fonts, miktex

Getting the following error when compiling a .tex file from a collaborator who is probably using another OS:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The t1xbtt source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/braz/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if

you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK font t1xbtt could not be created. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/braz/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Process exited with error(s)
```

I looked at the miktex-makemf.log and it says:

```
2017-08-05 09:16:45,573+1000 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose zplmr7m
2017-08-05 09:16:45,579+1000 FATAL miktex-makemf - The zplmr7m source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:39:50,717-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:39:50,723-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:19,916-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:19,922-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:22,343-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:22,349-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:23,852-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinBiolinumTB-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:23,856-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinBiolinumTB-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:25,415-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineTB-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:25,422-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineTB-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:26,103-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:26,108-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:26,833-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinBiolinumTB-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:26,838-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinBiolinumTB-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:27,571-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineTB-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:27,576-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineTB-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:29,097-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:29,103-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:29,789-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:29,795-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:30,503-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:30,508-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:32,015-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:32,020-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-15 11:40:32,699-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose LinLibertineT-tlf-ts1--base
2017-12-15 11:40:32,704-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The LinLibertineT-tlf-ts1--base source file could not be found.
2017-12-20 10:05:34,628-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose psyr
2017-12-20 10:05:34,634-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The psyr source file could not be found.
2017-12-20 10:05:41,762-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose t1xbtt
2017-12-20 10:05:41,769-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The t1xbtt source file could not be found.
2017-12-20 10:05:44,789-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose t1xbtt
2017-12-20 10:05:44,796-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The t1xbtt source file could not be found.
2017-12-20 10:05:54,259-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose t1xbtt
2017-12-20 10:05:54,267-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The t1xbtt source file could not be found.
2017-12-20 10:06:46,613-0800 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose t1xbtt
2017-12-20 10:06:46,620-0800 FATAL miktex-makemf - The t1xbtt source file could not be found.
```

I have no idea how to go from here, and web searches did not seem to help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Run from the command line `updmap --admin`. The messages mean that these type1 fonts are not found, and MiKTeX tries to make bitmap fonts instead.

Comment: That did it, thanks! You should write an answer so I can choose it. Anyway, how is a user supposed to know that?...

Comment: Well… asking on this site. It happens from time to time with MiKTeX. I agree it's not so easy for a beginner to know type 1  fonts  are found through a few databases called `dvips.map, pdftex.map,…`, which have to be updated each time a new font is installed. If you're interested in how it works, you can look the Philip Lehmann's *The Fonts Installation Guide*.

Comment: @Bernard Do you want to answer or is there a duplicate we can mark this as? I imagine there must be by now - if not, somebody should write one.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Not Windows?
Possibly, updating with elevated rights could already solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding these two lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
```

Comment: Why? Can you elaborate?

Comment: This is an old mystery. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/problem-with-sansmathaccent-under-pdftex

Comment: So is this a duplicate question then?

Comment: This is an old mystery. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/problem-with-sansmathaccent-under-pdftex and https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/discussion/33790/thread/af9a3a41/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133781/font-display-error-in-windows. The best explanation of have seen is that it is due to a confusion in a multi user installation explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22453/new-map-file-with-miktex

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard),

Run from the command line `updmap --admin`. The messages mean that these type1 fonts are not found, and MiKTeX tries to make bitmap fonts instead.

More information on Philip Lehmann's *The Fonts Installation Guide*.