# Writing in chinese with miktex and pdflatex : ttf2pk: ERROR: Cannot find `simsun.ttc'

Tags: pdftex, miktex, ubuntu, cjk, japanese

I recently switched from texlive to miktex on an ubuntu machine and I'm trying to use japanese characters in my PDF.

Here is my latex code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}

膝に滲んだ血

\end{CJK*}


\end{document}
```

(Don't mind the characters, they're just placeholders)

I launch it using this command :

```
pdflatex chinese.tex
```

I have a hard time figuring out how fonts work but it seems that miktex doesn't seem to load the same font as texlive and throws this error :

> (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document
>   Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/CJKutf8.sty
>   (/usr/local/share/miktex-texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/CJK.sty
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/mule/MULEenc.sty)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/CJK.enc))
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)) (hop.aux)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/UTF8.bdg)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/c70song.fd)
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'C70/min/bx/n' undefined (Font)
>   using 'C70/song/m/n' instead on input line 10.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `C70/min/m/n' undefined (Font)
>   using 'C70/song/m/n' instead on input line 13.
>
> (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/c70bsmi.fd)
>   (/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cjk/UTF8/c70bsmi.fdx)
>   [1{/root/.miktex/ texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (hop.aux)
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
>   substituted.
>
> miktex-makepk: warning: running with administrator privileges Trying
>   to make PK font cyberb88 at 600 DPI... The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
>   Running miktex-makemf... miktex-makemf: warning: running with
>   administrator privileges
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:
>
> /root/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log Running
>   miktex-ttf2pk... miktex-ttf2pk: warning: running with administrator
>   privileges Running miktex-ttf2pk... miktex-ttf2pk: warning: running
>   with administrator privileges ttf2pk: ERROR: Cannot find `simsun.ttc'.
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:
>
> /root/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log  ) !pdfTeX
>   error: pdflatex (file cyberb88): Font cyberb88 at 600 not found  ==>
>   Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I've tried to copy simsun.ttc in the same folder, without success. 
And I doubt texlive actually used simsun.ttc since I didn't have it either when using texlive.

I've also tried what was suggested here : [miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The t1xbtt source file could not be found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407052/miktex-makemf-did-not-succeed-for-the-following-reason-the-t1xbtt-source-file-c) also without success.

Do you have an idea of what is missing in this example ?

Comment: The common possibility is the font namebase needs to be refreshed via updmap at --admin level and user level.

Comment: I can't use updmap so I tried initexmf --admin --mkmaps which should do the trick, it seems. But I still get the same error :/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use ubuntu to be able to guide you through but if you have installed any dual system it is imperative to update maps both as admin and user more info at https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html and the referenced guide https://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide